# JQuery that will loop each row of a table's column and retrieve the value of its corresponding checkbox from another column if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

What I need is when the `updateTotal` function triggers (by checking or unchecking the checkbox), it loops the `itemprice` column and adds it to the `totalPrice` variable if its corresponding checkbox located in `tditem` column is checked. Otherwise, don't add the `itemprice`'s value to `totalPrice`.

```
<table id="tblItem">
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden" id="tditemid"></td>
            <td id="tditem">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckItemId" name="selectedItems" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal(this)" />
                <label id="lblitem"></label>
            </td>
            <td id="itemprice"></td>
            <td class="hidden" id="tdstatus"></td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>

<input class="form-control input-sm" id="total" name="totalprice" readonly="true" type="text" value="">
```

Javascript

```
//Update total textbox when checkbox is checked/unchecked
window.updateTotal = function (element) {
    var totalPrice = 0.00;
    //Get clicked dropdown row and col id
    var chckRow = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var chckCol = element.parentNode.cellIndex;
    //What to do??

    //Display total price
    $('#totalprice').val(totalPrice);
}
```

Comment: did you try to write something? where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need to loop the table and check if the column with the checkbox is checked. If checked, retrieve its corresponding price column and add it to the `totalPrice` variable. If not, ignore and go to the next row. Until now, I'm still researching on it

Answer (score 0):

Look on the code bellow

```
var totalPrice = 0;

window.updateTotal = function (element) {
    var jqEl = $(element);
    var isChecked = jqEl.prop('checked') === true;
    totalPrice = isChecked ? totalPrice += parseInt(jqEl.attr('data-price')) : totalPrice -= parseInt(jqEl.attr('data-price'));

    $('#total').val(totalPrice);
}

function init () {
    var elements = $('input[name="selectedItems"]');

    elements.each(function (index, item) {
        var element = $(item);
        var isChecked = element.prop('checked');

        totalPrice = isChecked ? totalPrice += parseInt(element.attr('data-price')) : totalPrice;
    });
    $('#total').val(totalPrice);
};

init();
```

You need to create `totalPrice` variable. Next i create a `data-price` attribute for better working with HTML DOM elements. There you no need to use something like `element.parent. ....` because this is not good approach. `init` function is like your constructor and will be executed at the start of the app or what is it.

Here is your [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Franky238/t23zt0wo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the checked inputs and then calculate the total based on their parent's sibling `.itemprice` element "value".

Also since you can only have one `#id` you can use a class for `.itemprice` which can be present for multiple elements.

```
//Update total textbox when checkbox is checked/unchecked
window.updateTotal = function (element) {
    var totalPrice = 0.00;

 $("input:checked").each(function(){
   totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).parent().next('.itemprice').text());
 });

    $('#totalprice').val(totalPrice);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/bBEGwP)**